# How to create a Text Editor in c++ without using any graphics library?

Tags: c++, file-io, editor, text-editor, codeblocks

I started out by declaring a string and storing all the text entered by the user in it. Then I transfer to a file. I cant figure out how add a line break to the input. I am just a beginner..

example code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string x;
    string y;
    ofstream a_file("example.txt");
    getline ( cin , x);

    a_file<<x;
    a_file<<y;

}
```

Comment: You'll probably have to think about the program flow and the interface before you start typing any code. Once you've done that, I'm sure you'll have a more specific question!

Comment: Yup, seems off topic. This is a massive topic!

Comment: How to create a Operating System in C++? :P

Comment: For a beginner the code looks very structured and cleaned up. You just need to `#include <string>` at the top of the file when you operate on strings, otherwise your program might not compile.

Comment: You will need some form of graphics library. Even if it is a low level library like ncurses that does all its stuff in a terminal window (go have a look a vim or emacs for ideas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a line break to the output, you need to write the string `"\n"` to it.

```
ofstream a_file("example.txt");

string line;
if (getline(cin, line)) {
  a_file << line;
  a_file << "\n";
}
```

It's as simple as that. You can also combine the last two statements into one:

```
a_file << line << "\n";
```

But if you want to add the line break to the string, and not only to the file, you can do this:

```
string line = "some line that has been input";
line += "\n";
line += "the text of the second line, including the line break\n";
```

Comment: thnx....i am new to c++(i know a little of C)....i didnt know you can use the"<<" operator to add "\n" to the file :P